# Attaching Tags or Multiple Tags in XML::COMPILE::SCHEMA

Tags: xml, perl, xsd

i have given an xsd file, an Perl Enviroment and can only use
    `XML::LibXML , XML::SAX, XML::Compile`

Relevant Part from xsd is

```
<complexType name="property">
<attribute type="propertyvalue" name="name" use="required"/>
<attribute type="string" name="value" use="required"/>
</complexType>
<simpleType name="propertyvalue">
<restriction base="string">
<enumeration value="propertya"/>
<enumeration value="propertyb"/>
  [....some more values...]
</restriction>   
</simpleType>
```

I've got to write multiple propertys for every value.
As up to now, i worked with XML::Compile::Schema

```
$schema->template('PERL', $type); 
my $doc    = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0', 'UTF-8');
my $write  = $schema->compile(WRITER => $type, use_default_namespace => 1);
my %hash;
$hash = {
properties =>
            {
             version => 42,
             property =>
                        [ {name => "propertya",
                           value => "example",
                        }, ],
            }   
        };
my $xml= $write->($doc, $hash);
$doc->setDocumentElement($xml);
```

My problem by now is, i cant see a way how i can add more than one property tag with somesing like

```
@properties =("propertya","propertyb",[.and so on.]);
foreach my $pname (@properties){
$hash = {
          properties =>
          { 
                       version => 42,
                       property =>
                                  [ {name => $pname;
                                     value => "example",
                                  }, ],
        }   
};
my $xml= $write->($doc, $hash);
$doc->setDocumentElement($xml);
}
```

without overwriting everything or getting Messages that other parts of the file are missing.
Is there anyway to do this, and is there a way to attach tags lateron after executing
    `my $xml = $write->($doc, $hash);`
?

Comment: it looks like property is just an anonymous array, containing anonymous hashes. Cant you just used your foreach loop to build the array then create your xml once giving it the reference to the propertys array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of propery in your hash is just an annonymous array / array reference. So you can simply process your properties into name values pairs in the foreach loop and push them on to an array. Then you only need create the xml hash once and give it the reference to the props array you built in the foreach loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @properties=("propertya","propertyb","propertyc");
my @props;
foreach my $pname (@properties){
        push(@props, {name=>$pname, value=>'example'});
}

my $hash = {
properties =>
            {
             version => 42,
             property => \@props
            }
};

print Dumper $hash
```

as you can see the property now has an array of properties.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'properties' => {
                            'version' => 42,
                            'property' => [
                                            {
                                              'value' => 'example',
                                              'name' => 'propertya'
                                            },
                                            {
                                              'value' => 'example',
                                              'name' => 'propertyb'
                                            },
                                            {
                                              'value' => 'example',
                                              'name' => 'propertyc'
                                            }
                                          ]
                          }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks. But seeing it right, there is no way to attach tags after doing
    my $xml= $write->($doc, $hash);
    $doc->setDocumentElement($xml);
?
Anyhow, after some fittings, it worked out, appreciate your help :)